# Origin of common list-processing function names

Tags: history, list, higher-order-functions

Some higher-order functions for operating on lists or arrays have been repeatedly adopted or reinvented.  The functions **map**, **fold**[**l**|**r**], and **filter** are found together in several programming languages, such as Scheme, ML, and Python, that don't seem to have a common ancestor.  I'm going with these three names to keep the question focused.

To show that the names are not universal, here is a sampling of names for equivalent functionality in other languages.  C++ has *transform* instead of *map* and *remove_if* instead of *filter* (reversing the meaning of the predicate).  Lisp has *mapcar* instead of *map*, *remove-if-not* instead of *filter*, and *reduce* instead of *fold* (Some modern Lisp variants have *map* but this appears to be a [derived form](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node143.html#15518).)  C# uses *Select* instead of *map* and *Where* instead of *filter*.  C#'s names came from SQL via [LINQ](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/emeijer/papers/es012-meijer.pdf), and despite the name changes, their functionality was influenced by Haskell, which was itself influenced by ML.

The names *map*, *fold*, and *filter* are widespread, but not universal.  This suggests that they were borrowed from an influential source into other contemporary languages.  Where did these function names come from?

Comment: `map` would come from mathematical set theory, which describes set transformations as "mappings" from the input domain to the output range.

Comment: Lisp's `mapcar` is a map, on the [car](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR) (rather than the cdr).

Comment: fold got it's name because in set theory it's called catamorphism but that's just absolutely ridiculous. Also foldl is Aggregate in LINQ, again from SQL terminology.

Comment: Also note that while those languages don't have common ancestors officially, there absolutely has been a lot of influence, back and forth. Guido van Rossum had done his homework when he started designing Python, and Scheme, Common Lisp, Perl and (IIRC) Haskell and ML were already around at the time.

Comment: `filter` does exactly that - it filters the data. Seems pretty obvious.

Comment: I would say all of them originate from math. Mapping transformation and folding all refer to [linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) some people might have found that naming difficult to understand for the non-maths people and thought of "easier to apply" names

Comment: Just an aside: Haskell got the names from Miranda, not ML. It may be miranda took them from ML, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AidanCully, your explanation of the choice of `map` as a function name is quite strange: in mathematics a *map* means a *function*, all functions in (common) mathematics are between sets. By a *transformation* i suppose you again mean a *function*.  So calling a function `map` is a bit like calling it `function`.

Answer (score 4):

The only universal word in your list is `map` and it already appears in [the original paper on Lisp](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html) in 1960 (under the guise of `maplist`). 
The paper also has `search` (AKA `filter`, AKA `remove-if-not`).

I think the reason `map` endured while the others have variants is that [`map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28mathematics%29) comes from *relatively* ancient, established, common & elementary math while [`catamorphism`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism) (AKA `reduce` AKA `fold` &c) is a *relatively* advanced concept, from a *relatively* obscure recently developed (more or less simultaneously with CS) [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), and it was introduced (in the late 1980-ies) when  [`reduce`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm) was available in Lisp for over a *decade*.

Others (`filter` AKA `remove-if-not`) are even more ad hoc in CS/programming, so people felt even more comfortable picking their own name for them.

Comment: Don't vaguely refer to [Category theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) as "an obscure recently developed domain" also it is about as "recently developed" as [Lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Comment: @DanD.: the key word is *relatively*

Comment: Even then, they all got buggered in .NET so that they would be similar to SQL. (map -> Select; filter -> Where; fold -> Aggregate)